# Multiple sets of coefficients from logistic regression

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using ScikitLearn and am very new to data mining. I usually get one set of coefficients but this time I got 3 sets of coefficients. How can I convert it to a single coefficient or make it meaningful?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you working with a multiclass problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you mention which more sets of coefficients you are obtaining?

The number of coefficients is related to the number of variables that the regressor has.

Comment: I found some random "-" signs hidden in the regressor column. And one set of coefficients has been created for that. Thank you!